# FrameTicks Problem in DateListPlot

Tags: graphics, date-and-time

(I have MMA 10.0.2.0 running on a MacBook Pro with OS X 10.12.6.)

Before posting this question I looked at a number of interesting and helpful related posts: [Is FrameTicks broken in 10.1.0?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86625/is-frameticks-broken-in-10-1-0), [How to express ticks in scientific form?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9558/how-to-express-ticks-in-scientific-form), [About the number format in ticks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5369/about-the-number-format-in-ticks), [How can I manipulate the number of decimal places in the frame ticks?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33297/how-can-i-manipulate-the-number-of-decimal-places-in-the-frame-ticks), and [Changing FrameTicks of ListPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24979/changing-frameticks-of-listplot). I learned several things I did not know, for example that the `FrameTicks` specification changed from {bottom, left} to {{left, right},{bottom, top}} with MMA 7, but that the old spec was accepted until MMA 10. I also ran across, and installed, the `CustomTicks.m` package, which I did not know existed. My problem seems to be different, however, since it involves `DateListPlot`, which takes data in a somewhat different form.

Let's start with the data:

```
data = { {{2013}, 7.18956914`*^6}, {{2014}, 9.56534036`*^6}, 
         {{2015}, 1.048495813`*^7}, {{2016}, 8.38576746`*^6}, 
         {{2017}, 7.62914337`*^6} }
```

The extra curly brackets around the year lets `DateListPlot` interpret it as an `SQL` date spec (even if the month, day, hr, min, and sec are missing).

The first attempt was before I knew of the different formatting:

```
DateListPlot[data,
    PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.007], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]},
    GridLines -> Automatic,
    FrameTicks -> {Automatic, 
                   NumberForm[#, {8, 1}, ExponentFunction -> (Null &), 
                   DigitBlock -> 3] &},
    LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 13, Bold],
    PlotRange -> {{{2012}, {2018}}, {0, 15000000}},
    FrameLabel -> {None, Style["Volume", Bold]},
    PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[{"blabla"},
                   LegendMarkers -> 
                   Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Opacity[1], Rectangle[]}]]
     ]
```

[image]

As you can see, the year came out great, but there is nothing on the y-axis. The second attempt used `CustomTicks` and the correct formatting for the `FrameTicks` spec:

```
DateListPlot[data,
    PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.007], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]},
    GridLines -> Automatic,
    FrameTicks -> {{LinTicks, None}, {LinTicks, None}},
    LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 13, Bold],
    PlotRange -> {{{2012}, {2018}}, {0, 15000000}},
    FrameLabel -> {None, Style["Volume", Bold]},
    PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[{"blabla"},
                   LegendMarkers -> 
                   Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Opacity[1], Rectangle[]}]]
   ]
```

[image]

This time the volume labels on the left are roughly OK (I would rather have commas separating thousands) but the dates are messed up. This is most probably because `CustomTicks` was developed for physics problems rather than financial problems, and in fact dates are not mentioned at all in its manual. The last attempt is not to use `CustomTicks` and to try something a bit fancier with a function specification:

```
DateListPlot[data,
    PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.007], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]},
    GridLines -> Automatic,
    FrameTicks -> {{NumberForm[#, {8, 1}, ExponentFunction -> (Null &), 
                    DigitBlock -> 3] &, None}, {Automatic, None}},
    LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 13, Bold],
    PlotRange -> {{{2012}, {2018}}, {0, 15000000}},
    FrameLabel -> {None, Style["Volume", Bold]},
    PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[{"blabla"},
                   LegendMarkers -> 
                   Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Opacity[1], Rectangle[]}]]
   ]
```

[image]

Still no luck. I even got several error messages about `NumberForm`. One is telling me that `DigitBlock` should be a positive integer, which it is!! If I change `{8, 1}` to `{Infinity, 0}`, which I would prefer, I get a different error message telling me that it, too, should be a positive integer or a pair of positive integers.

The original objective was to get rid of the exponential notation for the volume and show it in decimal notation with no digits after the decimal point. The closest I got was with `CustomTicks`, but the year got messed up.

In conclusion, I am lost and would be very grateful for some enlightenment on how to deal with a problem that originally seemed rather trivial to solve.

Comment: do you get the desired result if you use the options  `GridLines -> {Automatic, FindDivisions[{0, 15000000}, 6] }`   and 
 `FrameTicks -> {{FindDivisions[{0, 15000000}, 6], Automatic}, 
   Automatic}`?

Comment: Yes! Thank you @kglr, that's great! I see I needed an additional hash.

Comment: My answer just above is to the NumberForm solution, which is now the answer I accepted. I also tried FindDivisions and it worked even applying it only to FrameTicks. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.007], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]},
 GridLines -> {Automatic, FindDivisions[{0, 15000000}, 6] }, 
 FrameTicks -> {{FindDivisions[{0, 15000000}, 6], Automatic},  Automatic}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 13, Bold], 
 PlotRange -> {{{2012}, {2018}}, {0, 15000000}}, ImageSize->500]
```

[image]

To have `,` as digit block separator, replace `FindDivisions[{0, 15000000}, 6]` with

```
{#, NumberForm[#, 8, ExponentFunction -> (Null &), DigitBlock -> 3]} & /@ 
  FindDivisions[{0, 15000000}, 6]
```

[image]